# Tableau datasource connect to other datasource

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

everyone.
We are using tableau and found slow down in case of using single datasource with multiple workbooks with various filters.

We have created multiple datasources with their own filters. But currently we have a headache when we need to update tds due to updated db schema.

Example

```
table organizations ddl changed -> added new column that should be added to tds
```

Is there a possibility to create datasource with db connection (master). And then child tds that will connect to master tds?

Comment: one single data source can be configured and utilized for different reports, I think you have complicated the process

Comment: We tried to have a single datasource but it gets a great piece of data that we do not need for most of our clients. We need filtered data actually. And having connection with filters to the single tds slows down a process significantly

Comment: using multiple TDS for your clients will be difficult to manage in the future, but there are easier ways to manage. is there some way we can connect? i can have a closer look at the issue and suggest a better approach